# Limit a field to entries by entry type

Tags: entry, entry-type

Is it possible to have an "entries" field but only allow selection to entries of a specific "entry type" within craft?

I'm trying to use entry types as a sort of way to enable interfaces with chunks of content. Requiring specific fields for one type of content and different fields for another type of content.

I realize I could create many channels and accomplish the same thing, but these data structures are similar in a lot of respects with only minor differences (which are important depending on the context they are going to be rendered). So I would prefer to have an overarching channel with several types.

Comment: For example. We have promoted content on a page. That promoted content could be a promoted video|image|page|external site etc.

Rather than having 4 different channels for each of these I was hoping for  a "promos" channel which has all these as  entry types. And I would like to be able to create a field called  `promotedVideos` which allows the user to select all promoted videos without having to work through the clutter of promoted pages | images etc.

Answer (score 3):

Probably too late for you, OP, but the [Entries Subset plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/entriessubset) for Craft 3 lets you do this and more.